# Why is URI missing in CodeIgniter 3 routing?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, routes, codeigniter-3

As you can see from the screenshot below, my URL is host.com/manage/users/login?debug=true, however the Class/Method registered inside the profiler is the default_controller and it says `No URI data exists` yet it is moved to the `GET DATA`.

For `$config['uri_protocol']`, I've tried PATH, REQUEST_URI, QUERY_STRING, and AUTO. I've tried putting `$route['default_controller']` at the beginning and end of the file.

Since upgrading to CI3, no URLs ever resolve to the custom route controller or method, with or without regular expressions.

[image]

My .htaccess is below:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^preprocessing.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^dynohtml.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^wwwroot.*)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^wwwroot/images/favicons/taCharacter.ico [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} favicon\.(ico|png|gif)$ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%3/wwwroot/images/favicons/taCharacter.ico [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value short_open_tag 1
 </IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: From [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html): "The reserved routes must come before any wildcard or regular expression routes."

Comment: @Tpojka thank you, that helps rule out one more thing. Unfortunately, it has not made a difference.

Comment: Try to output `$this->uri->uri_string();` or `$this->uri->ruri_string();`.

Comment: @Tpojka, good idea i did try: uri_string() returns empty and ruri_string() returns the default_controller path. I am using Module Extensions (HMVC) which might be effecting this as well, however, these routes are failing before i try to execute any module at all.

Comment: @Tpojka, i wrote a different question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351247/how-to-route-uris-to-application-controllers-still-use-modulerun-in-ci3-with - that stems from the same problem and might explain the situation a bit better. any help is greatly appreciated.