# How to route URIs to application/controllers & still use Module::run in CI3 with HMVC

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

I only use the modules for partial views, they are never routed to directly. Instead I have main controllers inside `application/controllers` and views inside `application/views/` which execute `Modules::run($moduleName, $params);` This invokes the module and renders fine, when reached.

The problem is **none of my routes are calling their `application/controller/` methods**. Meaning my routing has stopped working entirely and only the homepage defined by my `route['default_controller']` works. Because my main template file in `application/views` calls Modules::run($moduleName, $params) successfully, **I can verify the modules and HMVC is working fine independently.**

I recently upgrade from CodeIgniter 2 to 3 as well as the [Module Extensions - HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) package from  WireDesignz. See the picture for directory struction and relevant files.

[image]

@ /application/config/routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "dashboardcontroller/index";
$route['playlist(|.+?)'] = "dashboardcontroller/custommethod";
```

@ /application/controllers/Dashboardcontroller.php (note `die()` statements):

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class dashboardcontroller extends MX_Controller {

    private $data = array("pagi"=>array(), "me"=>array(), 'errors'=>null);

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index() {
        die("THIS IS THE ONLY THING EVER HIT");
    }   
    function custommethod($moduleName, $params) {
         die("THIS IS NEVER HIT");      
    }
}
```

When I change Dashboardcontroller.php to extend CI_Controller I get a cascade of errors starting with MX/Base.php re-declaring the CI class.

***How can I route URIs to application/controllers and still use Module::run($moduleName, $params)?***

Comment: What do you get using Modules:: in `APPPATH."controllers"` and not in modules directory? If you need `Modules::` static methods just use HMVC way.

Comment: @Tpojka, I created a module from my Dashboardcontroller and routed to it via `default_controller`, but `$this->uri->uri_string()` is still empty and thus nothing reallly works.

Comment: Can you use CI cards for segments such are `(:any)` and `(:num)` in a way?